# Using String function is not outputting Using Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to output a code from the EEPROM like the following 00:00:00:00:00 but when I run the code on the arduino nothing is outputting and I am not getting any errors

Does anyone know what am doing wrong?

```
    String ReadKeyCode(){
      String keyFormat;

       for (int i=0; i <= 4; i++){
          int key1 = EEPROM.read(i);
          keyFormat += key1+":"+keyFormat;
       } 

        return keyFormat;
    }

void setup(){
   Serial.println(ReadKeyCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `setup` routine needs to open or define the serial line.  The following code was copied from the Arduino web site and then modified:

```
void setup() {
  // open the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // initialize control over the keyboard:
  // Keyboard.begin();
  // or use Serial.println("Hello World, Goodnight moon!");

  // can do "one" time work here
}
```

What you code next begins on what you want to do!

That is, approach this problem in increments.  First get something simple like just a `setup()` routine to work.  Then add code to a `loop()` routine, etc.  In this method, if you have a problem you can always fall back to a previous version of the code that worked.

Comment: @UchiaItachi, what do you mean by "it"? On the Arduino you basically have a `setup()` and a `loop()` available for writing code in.  You can add your own routines but they must be called from `setup` or `loop`.